# How to get array data from HTML form?

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I have a form in HTML, and it stores data into array structure.

```
echo '<input type="text" style="text-align:right;" size="5" name="row[1][kidname]" />';
echo '<input type="text" type="number" style="text-align:right;" size="5" name="row[1][kidweight]" />';
echo '<input type="text" type="number" style="text-align:right;" size="5" name="row[1][kidheight]" />';

echo '<input type="text" style="text-align:right;" size="5" name="row[2][kidname]" />';
echo '<input type="text" type="number" style="text-align:right;" size="5" name="row[2][kidweight]" />';
echo '<input type="text" type="number" style="text-align:right;" size="5" name="row[2][kidheight]" />';
```

Supposed I need to get the second kid's weight value, how should I do? I have tried:

```
$_POST[row[2][kidweight];

$_POST['row[2][kidweight'];
```

Comment: `$_POST['row'][2]['kidweight'];`

Comment: Hi thanks for your fast reply, if I want to change it to index ( i ) , will it looks like this ? $_POST['row'][$i]['kidweight'];

Comment: thanks Scuzzy it's working ! just some additional information I have changed it to index : $_POST['row'][$i]['kidweight'];

Comment: Yep, or you can do `foreach( $_POST['row'] as $key => $row ){ echo $value['kidweight']; }`

Comment: great ! thanks Scuzzy for your info

Answer (score 1):

You can try also.

```
$_GET['row'][2]['kidweight'];
```

Comment: get? the OP said post